# Carriage Return not getting printed in the end of line

Tags: carriage-return

I have got a PeopleSoft AppEngine program generating an output. All the lines in the output are expected to end with CRLF (CarriageReturn + LineFeed). But the program is not generating CR. Each line is ending only with the LF. 
Does this have any OS level parameters to be set, or in anyway related to the DB level settings? 
Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the line of code that produces such an output line? Are you sure that AppEngine isn't "_fixing_" your line endings for you?